# Recovering the node with maximum in-degree and retrieving its longitude and latitude

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I am new to osmnx, openstreatmap and nominatim. I am trying to retrieve a node with the highest/maximum in-degree using in_degree_centrality networkx function.However, only degree_centrality and betweenness_centrality are present in the extended_stats dicts. How do I locate this node?. Do I have to convert the place network to a directed graph before I could use the in_degree_centrality function in Networkx or osmnx does it directly?

```
import osmnx as ox, networkx as nx, matplotlib.cm as cm, pandas as pd, numpy as np
place = 'City of Lethbridge, Alberta, Canada'
gdf = ox.gdf_from_place(place)
area = ox.project_gdf(gdf).unary_union.area
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive_service')

# calculate basic and extended network stats, merge them together, and display
stats = ox.basic_stats(G, area=area)
extended_stats = ox.extended_stats(G, ecc=True, bc=True, cc=True)
for key, value in extended_stats.items():
    stats[key] = value
pd.Series(stats)

# unpack dicts into individiual keys:values
stats = ox.basic_stats(G, area=area)
for k, count in stats['streets_per_node_counts'].items():
    stats['int_{}_count'.format(k)] = count
for k, proportion in stats['streets_per_node_proportion'].items():
    stats['int_{}_prop'.format(k)] = proportion

# delete the no longer needed dict elements
del stats['streets_per_node_counts']
del stats['streets_per_node_proportion']

# load as a pandas dataframe
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(stats)).T

G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
max_node, max_bc = max(extended_stats['betweenness_centrality'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(max_node, max_bc)


nc = ['r' if node==max_node else '#336699' for node in G_projected.nodes()]
ns = [50 if node==max_node else 8 for node in G_projected.nodes()]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_projected, node_size=ns, node_color=nc, node_zorder=2)



G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
in_degree= in_degree_centrality(G_projected) # computing the in_degree 
max_node_deg, max_in_deg= max(in_degree['in_degree_centrality'])
```

Node with maximum in-degree with its NodeId and longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.stats.extended_stats), in-degree centrality is not included in its built-in network stats calculation. However, as OSMnx produces a NetworkX MultiDiGraph object, you can call [NetworkX's implementation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.in_degree_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.in_degree_centrality) to calculate it.

To retrieve the lat-long, you just identify the node with the highest in-degree centrality, then inspect that nodes attributes (including lat-long) in the graph object.